# Changing the label position of one item in a layer at QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am working on a mapping project of Australia and need to display the layer labels respectively to other project items.
So, I have placed the labels in the center quadrant of the polygon.

[image]

And then I pushed them done the Y axis by three millimeters

[image]

However, I want to push done only the label Of Western Australia and no other label from this layer.
Is it passable to change the position of only one label from the same layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

15Steps proposal is a nice idea for single or few labels. In real life, you sooner or later will want to move more labels in different directions.

For this, you could either use the [**Layer to labeled layer plugin**](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/toLabeledLayer/) to get access to all label properties and set them individually (this plugin ist just a helper which created lot of additional columns and sets the dependencies), or, just for moving, add an **X** and **Y** column to your layer and set (see screen shot of 15Step) in the section *Data defined* -> *Coordinate X* and *Coordinate Y* to those columns.

You can now activate the "*Move label*"-button in the editable layer and drag the label to the desired position. The new coordinates of that label will be stored in the attribute table, the rest of the labels will still be placed by the general rules you give to the layer.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3, you can change the position and other attributes of individual labels interactively without using a plugin. QGIS 3 can set up the required auxiliary data attributes automatically, without altering the data of the layer itself:

[image]

A good write-up of the new functionality can be found in the blog post [Auxiliary Storage support in QGIS 3](http://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/)

Comment: I want to add that for a very similar functionality and UI in QGIS 2.x you can use the EasyCustomLabelling plugin, except that instead of auxiliary storage it saves the data in a memory layer (so use the Memory Layer Saver plugin as well).
But OP, if you can, do try it out in QGIS 3!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible by setting the expression next to the Offset X,Y field:

[image]

Click on edit, and enter the following expression into the Field Calculator.
 Just replace "name" with the name of the field containing your data and a **string** with the required Offset X,Y parameters:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "name" = 'Western Australia' THEN '0,10'
  ELSE '0,0'
END
```

After that, you will also notice the icon turns to yellow, like this: [image].